# Where can I find some more information about building Vim

Tags: vim

Recently I have found that there are many hidden functionalities in Vim.

So I decide to recompile it(version 7.4) to enable all its functionality.

Unlucky, the documentation I have seen so far is mostly about how to build a normal vim, but not a one with full functionalities.

Therefore, can anyone recommand more information about how to build this?

BTW, I wonder why the vim with full functionalities enabled is not the default choice?

Comment: Can you perhaps describe what "hidden functionality" you are specifically trying to enable?

Comment: Well, currently I want to enable *clipboard* and *balloon_eval*.

Comment: In the output `./configure --help` from vim are some detailed descriptions how to add additional packages or optional features. Did you try building it with those?

Comment: Like `--enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]`? Oh, let me try it.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to look at the [`README` in Vim's source code repository](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/README.txt), you'd discover that all the details for building the source code are contained in the [`src/INSTALL` file](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/INSTALL). It sounds like you are most likely interested in the section on *optional features* that can be enabled. Additionally you can find a list of the optional features available to `configure` by looking at [`src/auto/configure`](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/auto/configure). Here's a list I grabbed from the source just now:

```
  --disable-acl           Don't check for ACL support.
  --disable-darwin        Disable Darwin (Mac OS X) support.
  --disable-gpm           Don't use gpm (Linux mouse daemon).
  --disable-gtktest       Do not try to compile and run a test GTK program
  --disable-largefile     omit support for large files
  --disable-netbeans      Disable NetBeans integration support.
  --disable-nls           Don't support NLS (gettext()).
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-selinux   Don't check for SELinux support.
  --disable-sysmouse    Don't use sysmouse (mouse in *BSD console).
  --disable-xsmp          Disable XSMP session management
  --disable-xsmp-interact Disable XSMP interaction
  --enable-athena-check   If auto-select GUI, check for Athena default=yes
  --enable-carbon-check   If auto-select GUI, check for Carbon default=yes
  --enable-cscope         Include cscope interface.
  --enable-fail-if-missing    Fail if dependencies on additional features
  --enable-fontset        Include X fontset output support.
  --enable-gnome-check    If GTK GUI, check for GNOME default=no
  --enable-gtk2-check     If auto-select GUI, check for GTK+ 2 default=yes
  --enable-gui=OPTS     X11 GUI default=auto OPTS=auto/no/gtk2/gnome2/motif/athena/neXtaw/photon/carbon
  --enable-hangulinput    Include Hangul input support.
  --enable-luainterp=OPTS     Include Lua interpreter.  default=no OPTS=no/yes/dynamic
  --enable-motif-check    If auto-select GUI, check for Motif default=yes
  --enable-multibyte      Include multibyte editing support.
  --enable-mzschemeinterp   Include MzScheme interpreter.
  --enable-nextaw-check   If auto-select GUI, check for neXtaw default=yes
  --enable-perlinterp=OPTS     Include Perl interpreter.  default=no OPTS=no/yes/dynamic
  --enable-python3interp=OPTS   Include Python3 interpreter. default=no OPTS=no/yes/dynamic
  --enable-pythoninterp=OPTS   Include Python interpreter. default=no OPTS=no/yes/dynamic
  --enable-rubyinterp=OPTS     Include Ruby interpreter.  default=no OPTS=no/yes/dynamic
  --enable-sniff          Include Sniff interface.
  --enable-tclinterp      Include Tcl interpreter.
  --enable-workshop       Include Sun Visual Workshop support.
  --enable-xim            Include XIM input support.
  --with-compiledby=NAME  name to show in :version message
  --with-developer-dir=PATH    use PATH as location for Xcode developer tools
  --with-ex-name=NAME     what to call the Ex executable
  --with-features=TYPE    tiny, small, normal, big or huge (default: normal)
  --with-global-runtime=DIR    global runtime directory in 'runtimepath'
  --with-gnome            Specify prefix for GNOME files
  --with-gnome-includes=DIR Specify location of GNOME headers
  --with-gnome-libs=DIR   Specify location of GNOME libs
  --with-local-dir=PATH   search PATH instead of /usr/local for local libraries.
  --with-lua-prefix=PFX   Prefix where Lua is installed.
  --with-luajit           Link with LuaJIT instead of Lua.
  --with-mac-arch=ARCH    current, intel, ppc or both
  --with-modified-by=NAME       name of who modified a release version
  --with-motif-lib=STRING   Library for Motif
  --with-plthome=PLTHOME   Use PLTHOME.
  --with-python-config-dir=PATH  Python's config directory
  --with-python3-config-dir=PATH  Python's config directory
  --with-ruby-command=RUBY  name of the Ruby command (default: ruby)
  --with-tclsh=PATH       which tclsh to use (default: tclsh8.0)
  --with-tlib=library     terminal library to be used 
  --with-view-name=NAME   what to call the View executable
  --with-vim-name=NAME    what to call the Vim executable
  --with-x                use the X Window System
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --without-local-dir     do not search /usr/local for local libraries.
```

If you're using a branch of the official vim source, your distribution may have different options available. Running `configure --help` should list them without requiring you to go digging through source.

As for why these aren't all enabled by default, it's probably because they were deemed not broadly useful enough to everybody (or they require support libraries that may not be available by default). Really that's a question for maintainers of the vim, not SO.

Answer (score 1):

To build a fully-featured Vim, you have to:

- ensure you have all necessary development libraries installed (the `./configure` step checks for those and e.g. skips the Gnome UI if you don't have the Gnome libraries installed)
- pass `--with-features=huge`; note that the only difference between `huge` and `big` is profiling support
- pass `--enable-perlinterp --enable-pythoninterp --enable-python3interp --enable-rubyinterp` etc. if you want a particular programming language integration

You can verify the resulting feature set via the `:version` output.

---

If you're just waiting for functionality introduced in a later Vim version, it's easier to wait for an update of the official Vim packages, as provided by your package manager.

Answer (score 0):

if you check the archives of Vim's Google Groups mailing list, you'll find a long thread on compiling Vim with clipboard support (it's quite recent).

It's not as straightforward as you'd imagine but it's not insurmountable...